# What is the procedure to normalize a database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, normalize

I just took over a pretty terrible database design job, which heavily use comma separated value to store data. I know I know, it is hell.

The db is mysql, currently accessing it using MySql Workbench.

I already had idea in mind what to remove, and what new relations table needed.

So, my question is, how shall I proceed by migrating comma separated data to the new table? Any tools specialize for normalizing database?

Edit:
The server code is in PHP.

Comment: What language are you looking to convert the database with?

Comment: The server is in PHP. Sorry for total noob in this, do I need to write code to SELECT from old table and INSERT to new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define you new tables and attributes first.

Then, use PHP or Python or your favorite language with MySQL calls and write a 1 time converter which loops and reads the old table(s) and records and inserts the proper records into the new tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a standard approach? I don't mind doing it for now, but if I can learn the industrial way of doing it would be great.

Comment: In my experience, every case of normalizing poorly structured data requires a custom solution.  With sufficient experience in the sql calls, you will find this custom script to be rather easy.  There is no risk for existing data since you are only reading it.  Writing new production code for the normalized tables is easy to validate and test against the old setup.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are looking for standard practices. There are varying degree of denormalized databases out there. The ones I have come across have been normalized with custom code and tools.

SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) can be used for some case. In your case, I'd build a script for the migration that involves:

- creation of normalized tables
- creating stored procedure or PHP script(s) to read data from denormalized table, transform it and load it into normalized table
- creating a log table or log file
- performing the migration in sandbox; write logs while doing so
- version control the script
- correct the proc/script as needed
- create another sandbox
- run the full script on sandbox
- if successful, run the full script on prod (with logging)

SSIS is used for ETL in many organizations; it's standard tool for Microsoft BI stack and can also be used to migrate data between non-Microsoft DBs also.

Open Source ETL tool called Talend might also help in transforming your data. I personally believe that a PHP script will be the fastest and easiest to manipulate data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this is quite detail, however, SSIS is not free. But I got the whole idea.